# Android, Espresso, ListView: Test that item text = "some_text" and text color is Color.Red?

Tags: android-espresso

CursorMathcer, ListView. I has list of 10 items.

Also I has custom matcher that test text color:

```
    public static Matcher<View> withTextColor(final int expectedId) {

    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
            return expectedId == textView.getCurrentTextColor();
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with text color: ");
        }
    };
}
```

Test that find item with text **Some_caption**:

```
onData(withRowString(Item.CAPTION_COLUMN_NAME, "Some_caption")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This test scroll to item with string **Some_caption**.

OK. Test success pass.

But I also need to test that finding item has text color = Color.RED. 
How I can do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, what exactly is your problem? Is your "withTextColor" matcher not working?

Comment: onData(allOf(withRowString(Item.CAPTION_COLUMN_NAME, "Some_caption"),  withTextColor(Color.RED))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));  

 ---> get error: 

android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView'.

Comment: onData is used to match against the data in the adapterview, not the actual view itself.

Comment: OK, what is a correct test?

Comment: Here correct test:

onData(withRowString(Item.CAPTION_COLUMN_NAME, "Some_caption")).perform(click());
        pressBack();
        onView(allOf(withText("Some_caption"), withId(R.id.captionTextView)))
                .check(matches(withTextColor(Color.RED)));